# What are the valid TypeVar types in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-typing

Over the past several weeks, I've been taking an online class where we have to solve various problems using a variety of numerical methods. One of these was a Kalman filter, and the YT video I watched included the person using the following syntax:

```
def __init__(self, var_a: float,
                 var_b: float,
                 var_c: float,
                 var_d: float) -> None:
```

This seems like it's very useful for an end user to know what type of value to input to get the function started.

I've done a lot of searching on what the other valid types are, and cannot seem to Google the correct term. For example, "float" obviously works, and I know "list" works; however, "array" does not. These types may also be used to specify something other than "None" in what the function returns as well.

Does someone know of a reference, or what term I need to search?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called type hinting or type annotation.

You can use all types available in Python. Built in that is (a.o.):

- `int`: Integer
- `float`: Floating-point number
- `str`: String
- `bool`: Boolean
- `dict`: Dictionary
- `tuple`: Tuple
- `set`: Set

However you can also define types yourself by defining a class.
Also many modules give you more types. So for example numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def function(a: np.ndarray):
    return a
```

The `TypeVar` type is used when you want to indicate that a type is a generic type parameter.

Comment: You picked one of the worst possible "any existing" types: `np.ndarray` should not be used in hints, use `numpy.typing.NDArray[_DataType]` (e.g. `npt.NDArray[np.uint8]`) which is generic instead.